# Bluetooth dongle acting as keyboard?

Tags: bluetooth

I've heard that there are certain bluetooth dongles that act as a regular input device, just as if you've connected a regular USB keyboard, instead of just forwarding the bluetooth signal so to speak. I want it so that I can pair with the dongle instead of with whatever shaky bluetooth stack that is on the computer.

The specific problem I want to solve is that I have an Apple wireless keyboard that won't play nice with my machine and I was hoping that if I get a dongle that handles the pairing instead then hopefully it would work (and I could use the keyboard right at power up, rather than later when the appropriate libs have been loaded).

Are there in fact such dongles and if so, what are they called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bluetooth Keyboard / Mice usually come with an adapter but not always, and as you said, you have to pair them - This is good for laptops who have internal Bluetooth as you do not need anything extra.

If you do not want to pair, What you basically want is just a **traditional wireless keyboard**.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking about USB bluetooth adapters?  If so, as mentioned above, they do come with mice/keyboard combos.  When purchasing only the mouse or keyboard, not always.  Kensington and Iogear and several other makers also make them by themselves - even super small ones that are meant to be left in the laptop or desktop rather then being removed.